# Angular - When is session destroyed and memory cleared?

Tags: angular

I have an angular application which I have a 'remember me' checkbox that stores the refresh token locally (local storage) so that the user can come back to the application without logging in every time.  My thought was that when this is unchecked I would just store it in a variable in the application so when the application was terminated the refresh would no longer be stored, and they would have to log in again next time.

However, it seems like it's still remembering it... I did reload, close browser, try from a different browser tab, and it still seems to remember the token.

So the question is, what actually kills that in memory data?  Or alternately is there a way for me to tell when the user navigates away from the application or kills the browser and log them off/kill the variable?

Comment: Local storage is persistent one.

Comment: right... but when does in memory get destroyed?  It seems to be fairly persistent as well...

Comment: never - its persistent. You have to remove content the same way you put it in there (putting aside clearing browser data or dev console)

Comment: Session storage is probably what you need.

Comment: Session storage only exists for the current tab. When a tab is closed session storage is deleted. Local storage exists until the user requests it to be deleted or the browser determines it should be removed for security reasons. When the user checks "remember me" save the refresh token in local storage. Unchecked save the refresh token in sessions storage.

Comment: Ok, figured it out, session storage is indeed the right option.  However investigating to implement that I found a place where it was setting local storage on refresh and shouldn't have been so I think that was the root of my issue; I thought it was only storing in memory but it was really storing to local storage which is why it was persistent.  If you make it an answer I will accept.

Comment: Also downvoter why the downvote?  I am fairly new to JS still and was trying to understand the various storage mechanisms available and they weren't acting how I understood them so was trying to clarify that I understood correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here there are some hints to clarify even more the difference between local and session storage:

localStorage and sessionStorage are part of the web storage API, they are save in key/value pairs.

data is saved locally.

supported in all modern browsers,

10Mb for most browsers to be saved.

both accomplish the same thing.

only with session storage data is store until window or tab is closed.

only with storage session data is store until user manually clears the browser cache or until your web app clears the data.

an example